# Tkinter Progress bar without progress

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having a problem when plotting a progress bar and using Object oriented.
The following code creates a main window with the progress bar and three buttons but also another one. Why does the code create this second window?

In addition, the progress bar doesn't show a real progress. The buttons are configured to increase the value of the progress bar using the `step(20)` method.

I've set up a maximum value but doesn't seems to work.

Note: I need to create the `progressbar` variable before the `init` method to be able to call it in button execution command.

```
class Window(tkinter.Frame):
button1 = Button()
button2 = Button()
button3 = Button()
progressBar = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar()
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)

    master.title("Prueba JVS")
    master.geometry("600x600")
    self.frame = Frame(root)
    self.frame.pack()

    leftframe = Frame(master)
    leftframe.pack(side=LEFT)

    rightframe = Frame(master)
    rightframe.pack(side=RIGHT)

    label = Label(self.frame, text="Genetic JVS App")
    label.pack()

    button1 = Button(leftframe, text="Botón +", height=5, width=10, command=self.increment())
    button1.pack(padx=30, pady=3)
    button2 = Button(leftframe, text="Valor", height=5, width=10, command=self.display())
    button2.pack(padx=30, pady=3)
    button3 = Button(rightframe, text="Generar", height=5, width=10, command=self.button_clicked())
    button3.pack(padx=30, pady=3)

    #self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.master)
    # Barra de progreso.
    self.progressBar = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(self.frame, length=500)
    self.progressBar.configure(maximum=200)
    self.progressBar.pack(padx=10, pady=50)

    self.frame.pack(padx=50, pady=5)

def increment(self):
    self.progressBar.step(20)

def decrement(self):
    self.progressBar.step(-20)

def reset(self):
    self.progressBar["value"] = 0

def display(self):
    print(self.progressBar["value"])
    logging.info("Valor: %i", self.progressBar["value"])
def button_clicked(self):
    print('Button clicked')
    logging.info("Botón 3 pulsado.")
    self.progressBar.step(5)

root = Tk()
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The definition of class `Window` created three useless Buttons - this happened before you called `Tk()` to create a root window - so a window was automatically created to hold them. (You never called `.pack()` or similar on those buttons, so they aren't actually visible).  The real Buttons aren't working because you're calling the command functions yourself, and passing their return value (which is None) as the action to perform when the Button is clicked.  You want just `command=self.increment`, for example - no parentheses after it.

Comment: The indentation isn't correct. Remove all brace bracket  in `command=self.increment`, `command=self.display` and `command=self.button_clicked`.

Comment: `self.frame = Frame(root)` should be `self.frame = Frame(master)`

Comment: It works. Thank you all for your answer, it helped me a lot, also to understand what is happening.

Comment: Why not answer your own question? Also edit the code for correct indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code that works.

```
class Window(tkinter.Frame):

def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)

    master.title("Prueba JVS")
    master.geometry("600x600")
    self.frame = Frame(master)
    self.frame.pack()

    leftframe = Frame(master)
    leftframe.pack(side=LEFT)

    rightframe = Frame(master)
    rightframe.pack(side=RIGHT)

    label = Label(self.frame, text="Genetic JVS App")
    label.pack()

    button1 = Button(leftframe, text="Botón +", height=5, width=10, command=self.increment)
    button1.pack(padx=30, pady=3)
    button2 = Button(leftframe, text="Valor", height=5, width=10, command=self.display)
    button2.pack(padx=30, pady=3)
    button3 = Button(rightframe, text="Generar", height=5, width=10, command=self.button_clicked)
    button3.pack(padx=30, pady=3)

    #self.frame = tkinter.Frame(self.master)
    # Barra de progreso.
    self.progressBar = tkinter.ttk.Progressbar(self.frame, mode='determinate', length=500)
    self.progressBar.configure(maximum=200)
    self.progressBar.pack(padx=10, pady=50)

    self.frame.pack(padx=50, pady=5)

def increment(self):
    self.progressBar.step(20)

def decrement(self):
    self.progressBar.step(-20)

def reset(self):
    self.progressBar["value"] = 0

def display(self):
    print(self.progressBar["value"])
    logging.info("Valor: %i", self.progressBar["value"])
def button_clicked(self):
    print('Button clicked')
    logging.info("Botón 3 pulsado.")
    self.progressBar.step(5)




root = Tk()
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```